# Laravel unique request update

Tags: laravel, validation

Ive read some things about this on laracasts and Stackoverflow.

I have an update function with validation:

```
public function update(Customer $customer, StoreCustomer $request)
{
    $customer->update($request->validated());
    exit();
}
```

And the validation rules:

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        'code'  => 'required|unique:customers,code',
    ]
}
```

Now I tried to add a 3rd argument after the unique, so if it would exist it would continue. I tried it like this:

```
 public function rules(Customer $customer)
 {
    return [
        'code'  => 'required|unique:customers,code,'.$customer->code,
    ]
}
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything. It seems to work if you do the validation in my controller itself, but this looks way cleaner. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the right way to do this was

```
'code'  => 'required|unique:customers,code,'.$this->route('customer')->code.',code',
```

Since the $customer parameter isnt available in rules() you needed to get the customer another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the current customer, you need to change the `$customer->code` to `$customer->id`, assuming your primary key is `id`.

[unqiue validation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique)

Ignoring current customer:

```
'code' => 'required|unique:customers,code,'.$customer->id,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Form Request is a Request. It gets filled with the data from the current Request. You can pull the `customer` from your route as it is bound as a parameter currently. `$this->route('customer')`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'code' => 'required|unique:customers,code,'. $this->route('customer')->code,

        // perhaps this should be ignoring by id though?
        'code' => 'required|unique:customers,code,'. $this->route('customer')->id,
    ];
}
```

Using method injection here could only give you a binding, if one was registered with the container for that exact class, or a new instance of that class, the case here. There is no link between that class name and the concept that there might be a route parameter that currently contains a Model that happens to be of that class.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way do this with Rule:unique

```
return [
    'code'  => ['required', Rule::unique('customers', 'code')->whereNot('code', $customer->code)]
]
```